# Legend issues in amcharts

Tags: amcharts

Facing the following legend issues in Amcharts.

Issue 1 : Legend always occupies the available space on priority,leaving the chart compressed and illegible.

[image]

Issue 2 : Legend values truncated in case of lengthy legend.
Refer below image.

Issue 3 : If the value of the legend field is long, we are observing an overlap in the text, making it illegible to read. 
[image]

Comment: I think the PieChart is just not designed to hold that much information. Maybe consider using drilldown?

Comment: You could at least create a fiddle for testing purposes.

Comment: I cannot opt for drill-down just to reduce the size of data for pie-chart. My scenarios don't fit into it.Yes will get back to you with a fiddle.